# How can I stitch a set of images together?

Tags: graphics, image-editing

I have a set of images that are named `foo-N.jpg`, where `N` is a number from 0 to 100.

I'd like to stitch them together such that I have one long image, where `foo-0.jpg` is at the left and `foo-100.jpg` is at the right.

I can do this manually in Photoshop or Fireworks, but it'd take forever.

Is there a way to do this in bulk, like perhaps with Automator, Terminal, or an app?

Comment: This is off topic, try http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GraemeHutchison I'm asking how to automate a repeated action in OS X using OS X tools. I'm not quite sure how it's off-topic or how a site for photography would be able to answer an OS X automation question: can you elaborate?

Comment: OK its fine, thought you might get a better response from people who may do this all the time. i.e photographers. Seems you have the answer you were looking for so thats good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with Imagemagick from a terminal. If you have Homebrew, installing it is as easy as:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Once you have it, open the terminal and go to the folder where you have the pictures, then do:

```
convert foo* +append result.jpg
```

And there you have it, your 100 pictures in a row. You can also make a column with them, instead of `+append` use `-append`.